# Time Complexity Analysis for Non-ovarlapping Subproblem Recursive Solution

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Here I am just putting python code.

```
  Rec(Arr,N,K,X) :
     if(X==0 and K==0):
         return 1
     elif(X<=0 or K<=0 or N<0):
        return 0
     else :
         return Rec(Arr,N-1,K,X)+Rec(Arr,N,K-1,X-Arr[N])
```

Provided that all element of Arr are distinct,this conclude that all sub problems are non-overlapping(just took an small case, do it manually)

Please Evaluate Time Complexity in terms of N,K,X.
Thanks for reading this question...

Comment: What is wrong with my queation..everyone just downvoting it..can anyone point out issue?

Comment: At what complexity did you arrive? And why do you think it's incorrect?

Comment: @cristiano-sousa I thought as O(N*K)..I know that is wrong because I got TLE provided that N<=50 && K<=10.                   THANKS to #takoika..But I didnt understand his solution..but It gave me a hint that this solution will not work, i had to search for more optimized solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this problem is regarded as depth first search of a binary tree whose height is bounded by `max(N,K)`. So order of time complexity is bounded by `2^max(N,K)`. And then `X` and `Arr` might reduce this time complexity. But it is unclear because it depend on the values of `Arr` and `X`. (For example if Arr=[inf,...,inf], the time complexity will be `N`.)

Comment: Could you please explain little more ?

Comment: Assume due  X it never exit..worst case..than

Comment: 2^max(N,K) is upper bound without X and Arr.